# Accessing different members of a c union simultaneously

Tags: c, struct, unions, xlib, xorg

I've encountered a piece of code which seems to use different members a union at the same time:

```
XEvent ev;

if(handler[ev.type])
    (handler[ev.type])(&ev);
```

Handler is an array of functions. Here is the definition of XEvent:

```
typedef union _XEvent{
    int type;/*must not be changed*/
    XAnyEvent xany;
    XKeyEvent xkey;
    XButtonEvent xbutton;
............
} Xevent;
```

All the struct members of XEvent have an int as there first member. The called function uses the appropriate member structure of XEvent.

```
void
kpress(XEvent *ev) {
    XKeyEvent *e = &ev->xkey;
```

The problem is that `XKeyEvent` seems to use the value of its first int member as well to determine whether the event was a key press or key release.

```
typedef struct {
    int type; /* KeyPress or KeyRelease */
    unsigned long serial;   /* # of last request processed by server */
    .............
} XKeyEvent;
```

What am I missing here?

Note: The above code belongs to simple terminal, a terminal emulator. And all the data structures mentioned belong to Xlib.

Comment: Assuming having an `int` (in the original `union`) overlapping structures-with-an-initial-int is "safe" (my guess is it's not guaranteed to be, but probably "works"), then I don't see a problem with `XKeyEvent`'s _reading_ that value (presumably `KeyPress` and `KeyRelease` are two of the wider event-types that `XEvent` handles).  It would probably be safer to have a `struct { int type; union { .... } }` though.

Comment: @TripeHound: Except then you have two `type`s, the one in the outer struct, and the one that precedes each of the other types in the `union`. It seems like the goal is to have the `type` readable regardless of which `X*Event` was stored.

Comment: @shadowranger that is exactly the point - The X11 system sends around events as opaque structures. In case someone wants to know what's in there, he can check the `type` member and cast the union accordingly to access the actual data members. That is some sort of "OOP in C"

Comment: Seems like this is just an obfuscated way of declaring `typedef struct _XEvent{
    int type; union { XAnyEvent xany; XKeyEvent xkey; XButtonEvent xbutton;} ` where each struct XAnyEvent  and so on does not have the `type` member.

Comment: @Lundin it makes coding a bit easier and sometimes even more clear - You can access the event type both *with* and *without* a cast to the inner struct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It took a while until I understood where you think your problem is - Because actually, there is none...

You seem to be assuming that there must be a 1:1 relationship between event type ints and structures valid in the union. No, there isn't.

What Xlib does is: It will put the same XKeyEvent structure for both KeyPress and KeyRelease events (they use the same data members, thus can be used for both event cases).

The X11 windowing system sends around XEvents as *opaque structures* (or in OOP terminology "base classes") that the receiver *can* cast to the original structure (or in OOP terminology "derived classes") according to the event type. The overlapping `int` member "type" is used as a type selector.

This is done to be able to "route" events in generic code to the right place without having to handle each event type. Only the interested party (the actual receiver) will cast the inner union to the correct type and "extract" the data members it is interested in.

Comment: Ahh, I got it now. `handler` has different entries for `ButtonPress` and `ButtonRelease`. Maybe the app doesn't handle keypresses and keyreleases differently.

Comment: exactly. `KeyPress` and `KeyRelease`, though. But buttons work the same.

Answer (score 1):

C99 (the previous standard of C) and onward to C11 nowadays, allow reading a union member even if it wasn't the last member written.

They state (and I'm paraphrasing) that the value of the last written member is reinterpreted as a value of the member being read (and if their sizes differ, it behaves as "one would expect"). That value may be a trap value, but the simple act of reading is allowed and not undefined behavior.

Now, the standard also specifies that if a union contains several member structures that share the same initial sequence, you can inspect the common sequence through any union member.

`type` in `XEvent` isn't a structure, but the standard says two additional things:

1. A structure pointer, suitably converted, points to the first member.
2. A union pointer, suitably converted, points to any union member.

So each `type` in each struct must reside at the same memory location as the `type` in `XEvent`. So whether you are reading `ev.type` or `ev.xkey.type` it will be the same int.

So what is happening in your code:

1. The union is used for type erasure. Only the `type` field is used to determine the correct handler. Nothing precludes the same function from being registered in `handler` on several values of `type`.
2. The handler knows what union member to look at, so it accesses `xkey`. Then it acts accordingly to the value of `type`.